# Recommendations for explanations of selichos

Tags: prayer-book, selichot, elul

The selichos for ashkenazim are quite difficult to understand.

Are there any peirushim on selichos for ashkenazim? (I know there are different versions, I'm willing to take a peirush on any version. Also, older peirushim are somewhat more interesting to me.)

Comment: @Double By reversing you making the question unsearchable. There are no PEIrushim.

Comment: @alb there are commentaries. Use your edit power to improve the post, not fiddle with transliteration to satisfy your personal preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Mateh Levi is a classic peirush, and there's a copy of Selichos with it at http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/23516, although a lot of the pages have ink blots or something that make them difficult to read.

There's also the Be'er Yaakov selichos (http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/49117 according to Minhag Lita, and http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/49921 according to Minhag Polin).